Collector (Java Streams) using StringBuilder hangs
I'm trying to implement grep in Java with Stream as part of a job training program. The code runs fine in Intellij but when I package it with mvn clean package it just hangs while calling collect (I'm omitting the getters/setters and some other methods)
class JavaGrep {
    public void process() throws IOException {
        Stream<Path> paths = listFiles(this.rootPath);
        logger.debug(this.outFile);
        paths.map(
            Path::toFile
        ).forEach(
            this::readLargeFile
        );
    }

    public Stream<Path> listFiles(String rootDir) {
        try {
            return Files.walk(Paths.get(rootDir)).filter(
                path -> !Files.isDirectory(path)
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error: IO Exception while reading root directory", e);
        }
    }

    void readLargeFile(File file)  {
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE]; // Buffer to hold 20MB chunks
            int counter = 1;
            long fileSize = Files.size(file.toPath());
            while (fis.read(buffer)!= -1) {
                logger.debug("Progress reading {} : {}", file.toPath(), Math.min((float) counter * (float)CHUNK_SIZE / (float)fileSize * 100.0, 100.0));
                counter++;
                String s = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
                Stream<String> lines = Arrays.stream(s.split("\n"));
                String chunkContent = lines.filter(
                    this::containsPattern
                ).collect(
                    new StringBuilderCollector()
                );
                logger.debug("writing to file");
                this.writeToFile(chunkContent);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while reading file " + file.getPath(), e);
        }
    }

    public void writeToFile(String lines) {
        Path outFilePath = Paths.get(this.outFile);
        try(
            FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(outFilePath, StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
            FileLock lock = fileChannel.lock()
        ) {
            Files.write(outFilePath, lines.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("error while opening atomic file channel for {}", outFilePath, e);
        }
    }
}

And the Collector class that I implemented:
public class StringBuilderCollector implements Collector<String,StringBuilder,String> {

    StringBuilderCollector() {
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<StringBuilder> supplier() {
        return StringBuilder::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<StringBuilder, String> accumulator() {
        return (sb, string) -> {
            sb.append(string);
            sb.append('\n');
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<StringBuilder> combiner() {
        return (sb1, sb2) -> {
            sb1.append(sb2);
            return sb1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<StringBuilder, String> finisher() {
        return StringBuilder::toString;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}

At this point I'm not sure where things went wrong, since I was able to successfully run this a few times before (maybe a resource leak?). So far I've tried:

Creating the output file if it does not exist
Printing / logging (accumulator seems to work fine, it prints all the lines it's supposed to print so I'd assume that the filtering part is fine. However the code inside combiner never seems to run).
Putting Files.walk inside a try() block although that gave me an illegal state exception. ChatGPT said the resource closes automatically when I call collect so I don't think this is an issue


You'll be able to determine where it hangs (if it is) using jstack

you would still need try-with-resources block around Files.walk() to ensure the stream is closed after processing. All operations on the stream (like forEach) must occur within this block to prevent IllegalStateException

I'd have to collect and return a new stream though (since without it it would just close and give me an illegal state exception)

You would use the try-with-resources where you call the method (e.g., try (var stream = listFiles(rootPath) { /* use stream */ }). Ultimately, the important thing is to make sure you close the stream in this case.

You can improve your code in a few ways. 1) Use Collectors.joining("\n", "", '\n") instead of your custom collector. It will still add line breaks after each element (one between each pair, and one after the last). 2) Don't read lines manually but use Files.lines(file.toPath()). Right now you may split a line if it starts before the first 20MB and ends after. Make sure to close the stream returned by Files.lines, preferably using try-with-resources.

The initial problem in your code is that you are ignoring the returned value of fis.read(buffer) which tells you number of bytes read in:
int len = 0;
while (fis.read(buffer)!= -1) {
    ...
    // then use len:
    String s = new String(buffer, 0, len, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

This avoids allocating a huge blank ended String and then using your trim() as in your answer. Unfortunately this fix still has a problem as it coulds still split a line part way. Better to read line by line such as with BufferedReader.
Your program is considerably more complicated than it needs to be as you've ignored many API calls of java.nio.Files. Much of your code in readLargeFile is a long way of reproducing one call to Files.lines, writeToFile is one line call to Files.write( Iterable ). You don't need to collect potentially 20MB of matches into memory structure StringBuilderCollector, because you can convert Stream<String> to Iterable<String> which can be passed to Files.write. For example:
void readLargeFile(Path path) {
    logger.debug("readLargeFile "+path);
    Path outFilePath = Paths.get(this.outFile);

    // This gets a stream of all lines:
    try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1) ) {

        // Make stream conform to iterable (NB one time use only)
        Iterable<String> iterable = lines.filter(this::containsPattern)::iterator;

        // Append all lines of iterable => output file, creating if not exists
        Files.write(outFilePath, iterable, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1, StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Java has a class representing runtime IOException:
        throw new UncheckedIOException("Error while reading file " + path, e);
    }
}

Your launcher does not need to use File:
public void process() throws IOException {
    try(Stream<Path> paths = listFiles(this.rootPath)) {
        paths.forEach(this::readLargeFile);
    }
}

And finally, Files.find could be used as alternative to Files.walk as it reduces filesystem accesses in the filter if you want the file attributes:
public Stream<Path> listFiles(String rootDir) throws IOException{
    // or for special/hidden files use (p,a) -> !a.isDirectory()
    return Files.find(Paths.get(rootDir), Integer.MAX_VALUE, (p,a) -> a.isRegularFile());  
}


Thanks! Just wondering, is there an easy way to set the buffer size with File.lines? Or would the performance difference be negligible?

Files buffer size is 8192 last time I checked and can't be changed. However the use of ever larger buffer size usually gives no or negligible performance improvement. Like most JDK internals, Files is well optimised and tested with that setting.

I found the issue. jstack showed that when the process hung, it was actually doing regular expression matching because the string s was nearly 20MB long due to the null characters (thanks @DuncG). I changed
String s = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

to
String s = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).trim();

to remove the nearly 20MB of null characters and the problem was fixed.
